# Импорт функции из другого файла

Tags: python, python-3.x

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. С несколькими вопросами.

Задача первая:

У меня есть два файла:
C:\pytest\One\main.py
C:\pytest\One\mymodule.py

mymodule.py содержит:

```
class example:

    def hello():
        print('Hello, world!')

    def fib(n):
        a = b = 1
        for i in range(n - 2):
            a, b = b, a + b
        return b
```

main.py содержит:

```
import mymodule

mymodule.example.hello()
print(mymodule.example.fib(10))
```

В этом случае я импортировал модуль целиком. Могу ли я вызвать импортировать только класс или функцию?

```
from mymodule import example
```

или

```
from mymodule import hello
```

Возникает ошибка:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'fib'
```

Задача вторая:
Файлы те же, но они лежат в разных папка
У меня есть два файла:
C:\pytest\One\main.py
C:\pytest\Two\mymodule.py

Как импортировать файл/класс или функцию?

Comment: про `__init__` не забыли?

Comment: Буду очень Вам признателен если поясните. С программирование столкнулся только неделю назад.

Comment: У вас в коде, надеюсь, с отступами не так, как в вашем примере? Вы ведь читали про отступы в `python`?

Comment: Да, читал. Прошу прощения, забыл на отформатировать при публикации кода. Сейчас поправил. Код mymodule.py выполняется

Comment: 1. У меня ошибки не возникло. В питоне у методов первым аргументом традиционно пишется self, если вы хотите статично вызывать методы (как у вас), тогда выше объявления метода `def ` добавляете декоратор `@staticmethod`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас не хватает Файла `__init_.py` в вашем каталоге `C:\pytest\One\`, чтобы правильно импортировать пакеты:

```
    __init_.py
    main.py 
    mymodule.py
```

Comment: Спасибо, проблема заключалась именно в этом. Я создавал обычные папку, вместо Python package. После того как я создал пакет, в нём сгенерировался __init__.py и модули начали импортироваться.